# bootstrap & navbar collapse don't work react (create-react-app)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm trying to use: bootstrap 4 navbar and it wouldn't collapse on react.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#supported-content

could someone explain why?
I'm assuming this could be because will need to amend to components to change states? but it is just my guess.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";
// styles
import "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

ReactDOM.render(
<nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button  className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span  className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div  className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul  className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li  className="nav-item active">
        <a  className="nav-link" href="#">Home <span  className="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li  className="nav-item">
        <a  className="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li  className="nav-item dropdown">
        <a  className="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div  className="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a  className="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a  className="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div  className="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a  className="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li  className="nav-item">
        <a  className="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form  className="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input  className="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>
      <button  className="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
, document.getElementById("root"));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Comment: I think you might need to include `bootstrap.min.js` from `../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/` to make it work. have you tried it?

Comment: well, this is embarrassing, because you are right :)

Comment: I'm struggling with this at the moment as well, and have found a few optional fixes. One article that seems to explain the situation quite well, however the recommendation is not to use bootstrap directly with React because it impacts the DOM: [https://www.bennettnotes.com/bootstrap-navbar-collapse-reactjs/](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/3394) There are also some comments, and apparently a fix, related to the issue due to height = 0 that were applied to [Github history](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/3394) My next step is to experiment wit

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try adding `bootstrap.js` in your `import`s after you import `jquery`:

```
import "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";
```

Answer (score 11):

The best solution for me was to import only the bootstrap collapse.js script in the navbar component to prevent mixing js scripts.

Include this at the top of your navbar.jsx component:

`import "bootstrap/js/src/collapse.js";`

Answer (score 0):

If it is Bootstrap v3, maybe try to change class `navbar-toggler` to `navbar-toggle`.

On npm page Bootstrap 3.3.7 is latest version..

Comment: bootstrap 4, as in the link

Answer (score 0):

If you use react be sure that NavbarToggle and NavbarCollapse are inside the Navbar tag

```
<Navbar expand="lg">
    <NavbarToggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
    <NavbarOffcanvas>
        <Nav>
            <Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Link eventKey={TPL_TABS.ACCEPTED} href="/">Accepted</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item>
                <Nav.Link eventKey={TPL_TABS.ARCHIVE} href="/">Archive</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
        </Nav>
    </NavbarOffcanvas>
</Navbar>
```

Comment: This is true if you're using react-bootstrap the OP